# How to merge two observable to another observable with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

How to merge two observable to another observable with RxSwift?
In my case:

```
struct ViewModel {

let items: Observable<[MediaAsset]>

init(type: Observable<AssetMediaType>, provider: DataProvider) {
    items = Observable.combineLatest(type, provider.rx.didAuthorize, resultSelector: { (type, status)  in
        return provider.rx.fetchMedia(type)
    })
}

public var didAuthorize: Observable<AuthorizeResult> {
    return Observable.create { o in
       //....
    }
}

public func fetchMedia(_ withType: AssetMediaType) -> Observable<[MediaAsset]> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
       //....
    }
}
```

but xcode build failed for reason:

Cannot convert value of type '(AssetMediaType, *) -> Observable<[MediaAsset]>' to expected argument type '(*, _) -> _'

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to fire at the same time you need to use a Zip

```
let zipped = Observalbe.zip(a, b){$0}
```

or in your code

```
struct ViewModel {

let items: Observable<[MediaAsset]>

init(type: Observable<AssetMediaType>, provider: DataProvider) {
    items = Observable.zip(type, provider.rx.didAuthorize){$0}

}
```

Comment: the datasource is get from provider.rx.fetchMedia which define below

Answer (score 0):

### Root Issue:

Your types are mismatched.

Assuming that those functions belong to DataProvider.rx, instead of ViewModel, This code:

```
Observable.combineLatest(type, provider.rx.didAuthorize, resultSelector: { (type, status)  in
    return provider.rx.fetchMedia(type)
})
```

returns an Observable< Observable<[ViewModel.MediaAsset]>>

but you declared items as an Observable<[MediaAsset]>

### Solution: Flatten the observable

```
items = Observable.combineLatest(type, provider.didAuthorize) { type,status in
        return (type,status)
    }
    .flatMapLatest { type,status in
        return provider.fetchMedia(type)
            
    }
```

Note: It's unclear how you are using status. I passed it to the flatMapLatest, but it won't be passed along any further.